# Can two Identical devices be present on the same bus in any PCI Topology

Tags: pci

As per the PCI standard, devices are identified on the basis of Vendor Id, Device Id and the bus no. All devices of same type have identical vendor id and device id. If I put two such devices on the same bus say bus 0. How will the PCI Software Subsystem distinguish between the two?

If such a case is not possible in PCI, then can such thing be possible through PCI Express Switch?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Bus_enumeration).

Comment: Still It does not explain what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Every slot has a hardwired DevSel signal which is used for device enumeration. 
The driver of a PCI device doesnt know which slot the device is in.
The PCI Bridge does that, afaik.

Comment: Again, from my pci driver, I need to access two identical devices (with same vendor and device id lying on the same bus). In pci_dev structure that I have to instantiate, I can specify the device id and vendor id and thus register pci driver using pci_register fucnction(). But now how do I take control of either of the 2 devices?

Comment: Are you writing the PCI driver?  Might be best to migrate this question to StackOverflow.